# Автогенерация кода в Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator, uml

QtCreator поддерживает разработку диаграмм конечных автоматов и UML-диаграмм. Но я никак не могу найти информацию, можно ли эти диаграммы использовать для автогенерации кода на с++?

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в Qt Creator выполнять генерацию кода, и если можно, то где об этом почитать?

Comment: Есть экспериментальный плагин: https://wiki.qt.io/ModelEditor

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо. Пока не понял, можно ли генерировать код из UML-диаграмм. Кажется, нет. Но по Вашей подсказке сообразил, куда поискать. Нашел [плагин для конечных автоматов.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscxml-index.html) Он позволяет генерировать код.